# Structure of variables not recognised when dataframe is a tibble

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

I have made a function which assesses the structure of an input variable and then performs conditional descriptive statistics depending on what the variable is, means and sd for numeric and frequencies and proportions for factors.

However, when the dataframe is a tibble the method I have used to identify the structure of the variable doesn't seem to work. Here is some toy data

```
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(a = round(rnorm(5),1),
             b = factor(letters[1:5]))
glimpse(df)

# Output
# Rows: 5
# Columns: 2
# $ a <dbl> -0.6, -0.2, 1.6, 0.1, 0.1
# $ b <fct> a, b, c, d, e
```

Now if we ask R what type of variable each column is using the `is.x()` suite of functions it fails

```
is.numeric(df[,"a"])
# [1] FALSE

is.factor(df[,"b"])
# [1] FALSE
```

But, if we turn the dataframe to a `data.frame` type object it identifies them correctly

```
df <- as.data.frame(df)

is.numeric(df[,"a"])
# [1] TRUE

is.factor(df[,"b"])
# [1] TRUE
```

Now of course I could just convert the data.frame to a tibble in my function, but I was just curious how to get the result I got with the data.frame with the tibble, or some equivalent workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to use `[[` to subset the columns from tibble or a dataframe which would give you consistent results. To differentiate between dataframe and tibble let's call the tibble variable as `df_tib` and dataframe variable as `df_dat`.

```
df_tib <- df
df_dat <- data.frame(df)

is.numeric(df_tib[['a']])
#[1] TRUE
is.numeric(df_dat[['a']])
#[1] TRUE

is.factor(df_tib[['b']])
#[1] TRUE
is.factor(df_dat[['b']])
#[1] TRUE
```

The reason why the issue occurs is how they (dataframe and tibble) react while subsetting with `[`.

```
df_tib[, 'a']

# A tibble: 5 x 1
#      a
#  <dbl>
#1  -0.6
#2  -0.2
#3   1.6
#4   0.1
#5   0.1

df_dat[, 'a']
#[1] -0.6 -0.2  1.6  0.1  0.1
```

`df_tib` returns a tibble when you subset with `[` whereas since you have a single column in `df_dat` it returns a vector. `is.factor` and `is.numeric` would always return `FALSE` on dataframe/tibble object.